# How to used the lower case controller name in CodeIgniter on Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, server, codeigniter-3

Normally we used the Controller name as initial letter in caps in CodeIgniter. But now I have to fix one requirement where I need to use lower case controller name and worked this functionality on Ubuntu server.

Comment: Why do you need this? Please update the question with the answer to that, so that readers can help you more completely.

Comment: Its one of our client requirement to show controller name in a smaller case, I tried these changes on localhost it worked but on the server, it's don't worked well.

Comment: It sounds like an unreasonable limitation that they should not care about. I suggest you create a story/ticket about the problem and then come back to it - it surely cannot be a priority. I wonder if you would need to raise a ticket on CodeIgniter's GitHub - I have not used it, but I wonder if it would need a core modification.

Comment: Of course, you could add some custom logging to the routing system in the CI core to see how it works - perhaps that would help discover how to modify it?

Comment: Yes definitely, I go for it now, let's see how it works?